# How to deserialize an array

Tags: c#, serialization

Here is the Xml I got from a website:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="[url]">
  <totalResults>1</totalResults>
  <movie code="134539" />
  <movie code="134540" />
</feed>
```

My C# classes :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("feed", Namespace = "[url]")]
public class FeedSearch
{
    [XmlElement("totalResults")]
    public int TotalResults
    { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("feed")]
    [XmlArrayItem("movie")]
    public List<MovieSearch> Movies
    { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("movie", Namespace = "[url]")]
public class MovieSearch
{
    [XmlAttribute("code")]
    public int Code
    { get; set; }
}
```

The TotalResults is always well deserialized but my Movies list is always empty, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[XmlArray("feed")]
[XmlArrayItem("movie")]
public List<MovieSearch> Movies { get; set; }
```

Try like this:

```
[XmlElement("movie")]
public List<MovieSearch> Movies { get; set; }
```

Comment: @DarinDimitrov Could you describe me your answer, please